# Related projects in workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am trying to sue the Dual Battery Widget from [here](https://github.com/artiomchi/Dual-Battery-Widget) I have cloned it and got all the librarys. When I try to add it into eclipse it throws a bunch of errors out.

The developer made the app in [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) so the libs are referanced differently. Hopefully some knows how to fix it to work in eclipse?

Edit: This is a list of problems that I get I think they are all to do with the lib's not being referenced:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
AbstractBillingObserver cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 94 Java Problem
AbstractBillingObserver cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 122    Java Problem
AbstractBillingObserver cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 123    Java Problem
AbstractBillingObserver cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 123    Java Problem
AbstractBillingObserver cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 141    Java Problem
AbstractBillingObserver cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 151    Java Problem
AbstractBillingObserver cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 152    Java Problem
AbstractBillingObserver cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 153    Java Problem
BillingController cannot be resolved    BatteryApplication.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery   line 43 Java Problem
BillingController cannot be resolved    BatteryApplication.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery   line 44 Java Problem
BillingController cannot be resolved    BatteryApplication.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery   line 55 Java Problem
BillingController cannot be resolved    BatteryApplication.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery   line 67 Java Problem
BillingController cannot be resolved    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 141    Java Problem
BillingController cannot be resolved    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 152    Java Problem
BillingController cannot be resolved    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 473    Java Problem
BillingController cannot be resolved to a type  BatteryApplication.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery   line 44 Java Problem
ChartFactory cannot be resolved BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 513    Java Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Sherlock').    AndroidManifest.xml /DualBattery    line 26 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Sherlock').    AndroidManifest.xml /DualBattery    line 30 Android AAPT Problem
GraphicalView cannot be resolved to a type  BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 91 Java Problem
GraphicalView cannot be resolved to a type  BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 484    Java Problem
GraphicalView cannot be resolved to a type  BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 513    Java Problem
GraphicalView cannot be resolved to a type  BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 521    Java Problem
GraphicalView cannot be resolved to a type  BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 528    Java Problem
GraphicalView cannot be resolved to a type  BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 570    Java Problem
IBillingObserver cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryApplication.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery   line 55 Java Problem
SherlockPreferenceActivity cannot be resolved to a type WidgetSettingsActivity.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 26 Java Problem
SherlockPreferenceActivity cannot be resolved to a type WidgetSettingsActivity.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 30 Java Problem
SherlockPreferenceActivity cannot be resolved to a type WidgetSettingsActivity.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 41 Java Problem
The import android.support.v4.app.SherlockPreferenceActivity cannot be resolved WidgetSettingsActivity.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 21 Java Problem
The import net.robotmedia.billing.BillingController cannot be resolved  BatteryApplication.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery   line 22 Java Problem
The import net.robotmedia.billing.BillingController cannot be resolved  BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 43 Java Problem
The import net.robotmedia.billing.BillingRequest cannot be resolved BatteryApplication.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery   line 23 Java Problem
The import net.robotmedia.billing.BillingRequest cannot be resolved BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 44 Java Problem
The import net.robotmedia.billing.helper cannot be resolved BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 45 Java Problem
The import net.robotmedia.billing.IBillingObserver cannot be resolved   BatteryApplication.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery   line 24 Java Problem
The import net.robotmedia.billing.model cannot be resolved  BatteryApplication.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery   line 25 Java Problem
The import net.robotmedia.billing.model cannot be resolved  BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 46 Java Problem
The import org.achartengine.ChartFactory cannot be resolved BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 47 Java Problem
The import org.achartengine.GraphicalView cannot be resolved    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 48 Java Problem
The import org.achartengine.model cannot be resolved    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 49 Java Problem
The import org.achartengine.model cannot be resolved    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 50 Java Problem
The import org.achartengine.renderer cannot be resolved BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 51 Java Problem
The import org.achartengine.renderer cannot be resolved BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 52 Java Problem
The method addPreferencesFromResource(int) is undefined for the type WidgetSettingsActivity WidgetSettingsActivity.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 36 Java Problem
The method getIntent() is undefined for the type WidgetSettingsActivity WidgetSettingsActivity.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 31 Java Problem
The method getPreferenceManager() is undefined for the type WidgetSettingsActivity  WidgetSettingsActivity.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 35 Java Problem
The method onPause() of type WidgetSettingsActivity must override or implement a supertype method   WidgetSettingsActivity.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 40 Java Problem
The method updateWidget(Context, int) in the type BatteryWidgetUpdater is not applicable for the arguments (WidgetSettingsActivity, int)    WidgetSettingsActivity.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 42 Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesDataset cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 88 Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesDataset cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 498    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesDataset cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 498    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesDataset cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 500    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesDataset cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 507    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesDataset cannot be resolved to a type    BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 513    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 89 Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 485    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 485    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 486    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 487    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 488    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 489    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 490    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 491    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 492    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 493    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 494    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 495    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 496    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 503    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 510    Java Problem
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 513    Java Problem
XYSeries cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 90 Java Problem
XYSeries cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 499    Java Problem
XYSeries cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 499    Java Problem
XYSeries cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 500    Java Problem
XYSeries cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 506    Java Problem
XYSeries cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 506    Java Problem
XYSeries cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 507    Java Problem
XYSeries cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 552    Java Problem
XYSeries cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 558    Java Problem
XYSeries cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 566    Java Problem
XYSeries cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 568    Java Problem
XYSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 501    Java Problem
XYSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 501    Java Problem
XYSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 508    Java Problem
XYSeriesRenderer cannot be resolved to a type   BatteryInfoViewManager.java /DualBattery/src/org/flexlabs/widgets/dualbattery/widgetsettings    line 508    Java Problem
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the following libraries in your *relative* `lib` path?

```
android.library.reference.1=lib/ActionBarSherlock/library
android.library.reference.2=lib/ActionBarSherlock/plugins/preference
android.library.reference.3=lib/AndroidBilling/AndroidBillingLibrary
android.library.reference.4=lib/AChartEngine
android.library.reference.5=lib/MixPanel
```

That is most likely where the errors stem from. Paste the errors if this doesn't help.

Comment: I have that in my main project.properties

Comment: @Matt No what I asked was if you have the _libraries_? As in `ActionBarSherlock`, `AndroidBilling`, etc.

Comment: Oh yes I have them in my lib folder

Comment: @Matt Okay, post the stacktrace and I'll try to help you out.

Comment: @Matt You know where it says `Please check logcat output for more details`, did you include the **logcat** output as well? Please **edit your question** and include the logcat output as well (don't use pastebin links).